# Why is only one of my compiler warnings suppressed?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, compiler-warnings, suppress-warnings

This is what my Suppress Warnings setting looks like in `Project Properties -> Build`:

[image]

Yet the only warning the compiler seems to be ignoring is the first, `CS0168`. I still have plenty of `CS0414` warnings:

[image]

Why is the compiler not ignoring `CS0414`?

Comment: try rebuilding your solution, if that doesn't help try deleting the bin and obj directories. if that doesn't work, surely that has to be a bug

Comment: Are you sure you set this in the correct project? Also, those warnings shouldn't be suppressed, the code they refer to is probably useless.

Comment: @DavidG I don't normally like suppressing any warnings, but I'm trying to trim them down to a list that affects me and code I'm working with.

Comment: It seems when I separate the warning numbers with a semi-colon *and* space.

Comment: I'm using Visual studio 2017 fully updated, and your exact suppression string works for me

Comment: Since you are setting project properties, you are suppressing those warnings for other people too. I realise you have thousands of warnings here, perhaps now is time to suggest to your team that you spend some time paying off your technical debt and fixing them all?

Comment: "when I separate the warning numbers with a semi-colon and space" Remove the space, maybe internally does something like .Split(";") and compares "[space]CS0414" == "CS0414"

Comment: Note that the warning suppression setting is per-configuration. Have you perhaps suppressed the warning for DEBUG but you are building RELEASE (or vice-versa)?

Comment: I have OCD and i hate warnings, however if they truly superfluous i disable them in code when needed. i agree with DavidG its time for a warning day

Comment: Just a guess: can it be that IntelliSense warnings are still shown although the build warnings are compressed?

Answer (score 0):

Don't include the prefix of the warning codes; just include the numeric part.

[image]

[**nowarn** compiler option documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/nowarn-compiler-option)

That said, admittedly it works both with or without the prefix for me in VS Enterprise 2017.

Another thought is to ensure you have the codes suppressed in the project that is emitting those warnings.

Comment: @TheGeneral Though [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/nowarn-compiler-option) suggest only the numeric part should be used.

Comment: @DavidG Hrm might be a difference between compiler options, and the proj settings and file, strange though,